Generalizing Putnam 2014/B5
Consider the following natural generalization of the game in Putnam 2014/B5. Some of these remarks have also been made by Kent Merryfield in an AoPS thread. The main question is in a blockquote below.

Rules: Let $G$ be a fixed finite group. Alice and Bob take turns choosing an element of $G$ with Alice going first. At each turn, a player must choose an unchosen element of $G$ which commutes with all previously chosen elements. A player loses the game when they have no legal moves. For which finite groups $G$ does Alice have a winning strategy?

We make the following observations about the game:

Lemma: The elements chosen in a game must form a maximal abelian subgroup of $G$.

Proof: Consider the subgroup $H$ generated by the chosen elements. Since the generators mutually commute, the subgroup $H$ is abelian. Furthermore, every element of $H$ must have been chosen (otherwise, the game could have been continued with the unchosen elements of $H$). Finally, if $K$ is an abelian subgroup of $G$ with $H \leqslant K$, then $H = K$ (otherwise, the game could have been continued with elements in $K - H$). Thus, $H$ is a maximal abelian subgroup of $G$.

Corollary: If $G$ has odd order, then Alice always wins. If $Z(G)$ has even order, then Bob always wins. In particular, if $G$ is nilpotent, then Alice/Bob win if $G$ has odd/even order.

Proof: If $G$ has odd order, then by Lagrange's theorem, every maximal abelian subgroup has odd order. Similarly, if $Z(G)$ has even order, then every maximal abelian subgroup must contain $Z(G)$ and hence have even order. In the nilpotent case, $G$ has even order iff $Z(G)$ has even order.

Proposition: Alice has a winning strategy iff there exists $g \in G$ such that the centralizer $C_G(g)$ has odd order.

Proof: First, if such an element $g$ exists, then Alice can choose $g$ in the first move. The maximal abelian subgroup $H$ chosen at the end of the game must be a subgroup of $C_G(g)$ and must hence have odd order, meaning that Alice must always win after choosing $g$. However, if no such $g$ exists, then for any first choice $h \in G$, Bob can respond to Alice by choosing an element of even order in the group $C_G(h)$ by Cauchy's theorem. Consequently, the maximal abelian subgroup $H$ chosen at the end of the game must have even order by Lagrange's theorem, giving Bob the win.

Question: Consider the following statements about a finite group $G$:
$1$. The center $Z(G)$ has even order
$2$. Every maximal abelian subgroup of $G$ has even order
$3$. For all $g \in G$, the centralizer $C_G(g)$ has even order
We have $(1) \Rightarrow (2) \Rightarrow (3)$. Do either/both of these
implications hold the other way?

Examples: Here are a few examples for various finite groups $G$:

As mentioned before, if $G$ is nilpotent, then Alice wins iff $G$ has odd order. In particular, if $G$ is a $p$-group for some prime $p$, then Alice wins iff $p$ is an odd prime.
If $G = D_{2n}$, then Alice wins iff $n$ is odd. If $n$ is even, then $Z(G)$ has even order, whilst if $n$ is odd, then any non-trivial rotation has a centralizer of odd order.
If $G = \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ (this is the original problem from the Putnam), then Alice has a winning strategy iff $q$ is even. Indeed, if $q$ is odd, then $Z(G)$ contains the involution $-I$, while if $q$ is even, then we can find a transformation $T$ with centralizer of odd order (Give $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ the additional structure of $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ and let $T$ be multiplication by a generator of $\mathbb{F}^{\times}_{q^n}$. Then, $C_G(T) \cong \mathbb{F}^{\times}_{q^n}$ has odd order).
If $G = S_n$ for $n > 2$, then Alice has a winning strategy. Let $m$ be the largest odd integer which is at most $n$, then the conjugacy class of an $m$-cycle has order $(m-1)!$, so the centralizer has order $m$, which is odd. Consequently, Alice can win for $G = A_n$.


A group with a maximal abelian subgroup and every centralizer $C_G(x)$ of even order is $(3\times 3)\rtimes SD_{16}$. This is easy to see visibly: a group of order $16$ acts transitively on the eight elements of order $3$, so each must have an element of order $2$ centralizing it. Thus $|C_G(x)|$ is even for all $x\in G$ as elements outside the $3\times 3$ have even order.
The subgroup $3\times 3$ is clearly an abelian subgroup, and as the $SD_{16}$ acts faithfully on it ($SD_{16}$ is the Sylow $2$-subgroup of $GL_3(3)$) there is no abelian overgroup of it.

I'm afraid I don't have an easy (as in, one can visibly see it) counterexample to all maximal abelian subgroups even order implies $Z(G)>1$. The group $G=PSL_3(4).2^2$ has order 80640, 22 conjugacy classes, and the orders of their centralizers are
$80640, 672, 288, 256, 240, 36, 64, 32, 32, 32, 10, 36, 12, 12, 14, 32, 32, 16, 16, 8, 10, 14$.
We can check that every abelian subgroup of this group has centralizer of even order, hence there can be mno maximal abelian subgroups of odd order.
Magma code below shows the orders of the centralizers of all abelian subgroups.
> G1:=PermutationGroup(AutomorphismGroup(PSL(3,4)));
> G:=Subgroups(G1:IndexEqual:=3)[1]`subgroup;
> AbSubs:=Subgroups(G:IsAbelian:=true);
> #AbSubs;
49
> {*#Centralizer(G,i`subgroup):i in AbSubs*};
{* 8^^7, 10^^2, 12^^3, 14^^2, 16^^14, 18^^2, 24, 32^^9, 36^^2,
64, 128, 240, 256, 288, 672, 80640 *}
> #Center(G);
1


I know that $PSL_3(4)$ has order $20160$, what do you mean by $PSL_3(4). 2^2$? Presumably not $PSL_3(4) \times H$ for some order $4$ group $H$ since such a group would not be centerless.

@Haran No. That group would ahve a centre. This is a group $G$ with a normal subgroup $PSL_3(4)$ and quotient $2\times 2$, but not the direct product of those two groups. One of those copies of $2$ acts like the inverse transpose automorphism and the other squares every entry in the matrices of $SL_3(4)$. This is the first counterexample I could come up with, I'm afraid.

Is it a semidirect product or does the exact sequence of groups not split either? Also, do you know whether the maximal abelian subgroups are all of even order?

The only abelian subgroups of odd order have orders $1$, $3$, $5$, $7$ and $9$, so definitely all maximal abelian subgroups have even order. So it's all maximal abelian subgroups having even order does not imply $Z(G)>1$. Don't know about the other implication, that might be true. There are four classes of complement to the normal subgroup, so it is a split extension.

Clearly, all subgroups of orders $1, 3, 5, 7$ are not maximal abelian since they are cyclic and all centralizers have even order. However, I do not immediately see why an abelian subgroup of order $9$ cannot be maximal abelian. What do you have in mind here?

@Haran I've given counterexamples to both parts. The one counterexample is obvious, the other isn't, so I give code that verifies it.

SmallGroup(720, 780) is a counterexample to "(3) implies (1)": every centralizer has even order, but it has trivial center. I'm not yet sure if it's the smallest counterexample (I'll check back in when I know). It also is a counterexample to "(3) implies (2)" I believe, because it has a maximal Abelian subgroup of order $45$.
EDIT: Found the smallest counterexample for the first part: a group of order $72$, namely the wreath product $S_3\wr C_2$. It also has a maximal Abelian subgroup of order $9$, namely its normal Sylow $3$-subgroup $A_3\times A_3$.
EDIT 2: Here is the smallest counterexample to "(2) implies (1)". Let $N=C_4\times C_4=\langle r\rangle\times\langle s\rangle$, and let $\alpha\in\mathrm{Aut}(N)$ act as the matrix
\begin{equation}
\alpha = \begin{pmatrix}
2 &3\\1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Now let $G=N\rtimes\langle\alpha\rangle$. We have $\alpha^6=1$ and $G$ has order $96$. Clearly all maximal Abelian subgroups are even order, since every element of order $3$ lives in a cyclic subgroup of order $6$. But $Z(G)=\{1\}$. To see this it's enough to show $\alpha$ doesn't fix any non-trivial element of $N$. If it did, then writing it as $r^as^b$ we have
\begin{align}
r^as^b &= r^{2a+b}s^{3a+3b}\\
a+b &\equiv 0\pmod{4}\\
3a+2b &\equiv 0\pmod{4}
\end{align}
The last two equalities force $a\equiv 0\equiv b\pmod{4}$.
